# mapply with arguments as two lists (one formulas, one vectors)

Tags: r, mapply

I'm trying to use `mapply` to apply `t.test` over two lists of arguments. The first list `formulas` contains three formulas and the second list `periods` contains three vectors that subset `my.data`, which I pass with the `MoreArgs` argument.

I can do the `t.test`s manually with a `for` loop (also below), but I can't figure out why my `mapply` use fails. Is this not the correct time to use `mapply`?

```
# similar data
my.data <- data.frame(CAR1=rnorm(150),
                      CAR2=rnorm(150),
                      CAR3=rnorm(150),
                      period=rep(1:3, each=50),
                      treated=rep(1:2, times=75)
                      )

# two lists to pass as arguments to `t.test()`
# `subset`
periods <- list(my.data$period == 1,
                my.data$period <= 2,
                my.data$period <= 3
                )
# `formula`
formulas <- list(CAR1 ~ treated,
                 CAR2 ~ treated,
                 CAR3 ~ treated
                 )

# manual solution works
ttests <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
    ttests[[i]] <- t.test(formulas[[i]], 
                          data=my.data, 
                          subset=periods[[i]]
                          )
}

# but `mapply` fails
ttest <- mapply(FUN=t.test, 
                formula=formulas, 
                subset=periods, 
                MoreArgs=list(data=my.data),
                SIMPLIFY=FALSE
                )

# with error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'dots' not found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split your data.frame according to `period`, you don't need the `periods` object.

```
split.my.data <- split(my.data, f = my.data$period)

mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {
  t.test(x, data = y)  
}, x = formulas, y = split.my.data, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

[[1]]

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  CAR1 by treated
t = -0.7051, df = 44.861, p-value = 0.4844
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.9277752  0.4466579
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
      0.1650074       0.4055661 


[[2]]
... # output truncated
```

*EDIT*

In the case where you want to subset factors based on a logical operator other than `==`, I would create a "split list" like so.

```
split.my.data <- sapply(periods, FUN = function(x, my.data) my.data[x, ], 
       my.data = my.data, simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! Good point! But what if my sample periods aren't mutually exclusive? (I'll improve my example.) Would you still suggest this approach? Is there no way to pass `subset` as a list?

Comment: I've added another example of how I would construct a list to be fed to `mapply`.